# Q - Display Text like Command Prompt in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to display text strings on the screen in a similar look to command prompt for windows, i.e. text fills the bottom-most line and stays on the screen as new lines are added below it? I feel like `Canvas.drawTextOnPath` can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a bunch of ways to do this, depending on what you're using it for. Here's what I would do:

1. Add a LinearLayout with `android:gravity="bottom"`, and add your TextView to that layout.
2. When you add text to it, use something like:

   ```
   public ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
   int lines = 20;
   TextView textField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

   private String concatLines(){
      String txt = "";
      for(String s: text){
         txt += s+"\n";
      }
      return txt.substring(0, txt.length()-1);
   }

   private void appendLine(String line){
      text.add(line);
      if(text.size() > lines){
         text.remove(0);
      }
      textField.setText(concatLines());
   }

   appendLine("> A new line");
   ```

The `android:gravity="bottom"` should keep your text field aligned at the bottom of the layout. Make sure the TextView's height is `wrap_content`.

Comment: So int lines defines how many lines of text are still in the "buffer" so to speak?

Comment: Right. This method obviously has some pitfalls, such as: if the buffer is more than the height of the TextView, it will be clipped on the bottom instead of at the top how you'd probably desire.

Comment: Ah, so the text history cannot extend beyond the top of the screen right?

Comment: Right. To do that, you could look into using a ScrollView to wrap the TextView (and auto-scrolling to the bottom), or extend the TextView class and change the way it draws text.

Comment: Can I also use a second array to hold all the text that goes out of the screen(by adding the line to the second array before I remove it) and then just have a page up/down button that cycles through that second array?